# How to search on full dictionary

Tags: elasticsearch, dsl

> {'name':'abc', 'description':{'value':'abc', 'test':124}}

I have a DSL query above. my key 'description' is set of dictionary,  Is the below query is correct

```
{
   "from":0,
   "size":1000,
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":{
            "query_string":{
               "query":"Pencil",
               "fields":[
                  "name^8",
                  "description^2"
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

if I want to search on particular keyword on dictionary then I can do `description.value.keyword`

Comment: what do you want to search ?

Comment: i want to search on every attribute. but i need to specifically add in fields also

Comment: can you please explain your use case with the help of an example ?

Comment: i want to search all the attribute in `name` and `description` in the dictionary,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If no fields are provided, the multi_match query defaults to the
> index.query.default_field index settings, which in turn defaults to *.
> It extracts all fields in the mapping that are eligible to term queries and filters the metadata fields. All extracted fields are then
> combined to build a query.

You can use [multi-match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html) if you want to search all the attribute in the `name` and `description` fields

Adding a working example with index data, mapping, search query, and search result

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "name": "abc",
  "description": {
    "value": "abc",
    "test": 124
  }
}
{
  "name": "John",
  "description": {
    "value": "abc",
    "test": 124
  }
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query":    "abc"
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "65824093",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.6931471,
        "_source": {
          "name": "abc",
          "description": {
            "value": "abc",
            "test": 124
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "65824093",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.18232156,
        "_source": {
          "name": "John",
          "description": {
            "value": "abc",
            "test": 124
          }
        }
      }
    ]
```

If you want to know which field is getting matched out of all the fields, then you can use [highlighting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/highlighting.html)

Comment: yes this i got, but i need to pass fields also,

Comment: @Nons can you please tell, which fields you need to pass and what is your use case for that?

Comment: `name` and  all attributes of `description` that is `value` and `test`.

Comment: if  i pass ["name^8", 'description^2'] will it search for entire `name` and `description` attributes

Comment: This i got it i can search by not passing the fields , tell me how to search on `description` only by passing fields

Comment: how to search on only `description` fields only